# About ipp image construction

Tags: c++, image, intel-ipp

I have an image stored in a pointer to char and I want to use on it ipp functions.
How do I build an Ipp8u* image in ipp from this pointer to char?
is this a heavy calculation (the construction)?
Can I do simple casting?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is cast the pointer:

```
Ipp8u *ipp_data = static_cast<Ipp8u*>(your_data);
```

or, if you prefer C-style casts for some reason:

```
Ipp8u *ipp_data = (Ipp8u *)your_data;
```

As noted in the [Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/501992), `Ipp8u` is equivalent to C's `unsigned char` -- at least in the typical implementation where `CHAR_BIT == 8`. This isn't required but I believe is the case for most (if not all) [compilers/platforms supported by Intel-IPP](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp-70-library-system-requirements/).

Comment: Wonder why they say `unsigned char` and not `uint8_t`, which is more explicit.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I can only guess it's because `unsigned char` is more common/widely known, but I'd have to agree that uint8_t would really fit the description more accurately.